# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in Android

Tags: android, installation

I am trying to build an application and keep getting this error, I can't seem to do anything about:

> Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

The Android manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ehealth"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <!-- First screen to load start -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- First screen to load end -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Profile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data />

        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Paramedic"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_paramedic" >
        </activity>
    </application>
    <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies




    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: I've removed the offer to add logcat information to the comments - this should go in a question edit, if it is required. Use the code formatting tools as per your XML. Also, we do try to discourage requests for urgency here, so I have removed that - from the title no less. People here are broadly volunteers, and they tend not to think highly of requests to hurry up! Please leave that out of your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
<meta-data />
```

`meta-data` elements must have an `android:name` and either `android:value` or `android:resource`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Was stuck with this for more then an hour.

Answer (score 0):

For reference (in addition to laalto's answer), if you're using Android Studio, it's worth checking Messages/Gradle Console tabs, as it may contains clues as to what's the problem. In your case, you could have seen something similar to:

> Missing 'name' key attribute on element meta-data at AndroidManifest.xml:37:9-22

[image]